# How to convert a ctypes C pointer to a Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I'm writing a callback function in Python:

```
@ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_ushort))
def FastModeCallback(hCam, x, y, w, h, binx, biny, imageBuffer_ptr):

    image = np.ctypeslib.as_array(imageBuffer_ptr, shape=(h, w))
```

How can I convert `imageBuffer_ptr` into a Numpy array of `shape=(h,w)` and `dtype=c.ushort`?

I read this answer: [Convert Pointer to Array of Unsigned Chars to Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616512/convert-pointer-to-array-of-unsigned-chars-to-numpy-array)

and this answer: [Getting data from ctypes array into numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355524/getting-data-from-ctypes-array-into-numpy)

Both advise using `np.ctypeslib.as_array` but when I try it I get this error:

```
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function FastModeCallback at 0x00000224E2992DC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dave\data\Code\Python\Cheese\atik.py", line 472, in FastModeCallback
    image = np.ctypeslib.as_array(imageBuffer_ptr, shape=(h, w))
  File "C:\Program_Files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py", line 521, in as_array
    return array(obj, copy=False)
ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string
```

Google makes it sound like this is a long-standing bug in Python (I'm on 3.8) - what is a workaround?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049957/numpy-error-when-converting-array-of-ctypes-types-to-void-pointer could help.

Comment: Also how are you calling the function? And what arguments are you passing to it?

Comment: @CristiFati It's a 3rd party DLL; I don't have the source and don't know how it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) and [[NumPy]: C-Types Foreign Function Interface (numpy.ctypeslib)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#c-types-foreign-function-interface-numpy-ctypeslib). The latter states about the following 2 items (**emphasis** is mine):

1. *as_array*

   > **Create a numpy array from a ctypes array or POINTER.**
2. *ndpointer*

   > An ndpointer instance is used to describe an ndarray in restypes and argtypes specifications. This approach is more flexible than using, for example, `POINTER(c_double)`, since several restrictions can be specified, which are verified upon calling the ctypes function.

*imageBuffer_ptr* is **not** a "*ctypes array or POINTER*" (**literally**: it's not a ***ctypes.POINTER*** instance, but ***ctypes.c_void_p*** one (there's a subtle difference between the 2)).

The *C* layer (which in our case lies in the middle) doesn't know about *NumPy* arrays and so on, so from its *PoV*, that argument is simply an ***unsigned short**** (doesn't have information about shape, ...). So, on it's other side (in the *Python* callback), you have to reconstruct the array from the plain *C* pointer. That can be achieved in 2 ways, like I did in the example below:

- ***callback_ct***: Use good-old *C* way: modify the callback's signature to use *ct.POINTER(ct.c_ushort)*. That is the most straightforward, but the drawback is that it loses all the extra checks when called, meaning that it takes any pointer not just a *ndarray* one
- ***callback_np***: Manually recreate the array from the argument (using a series of conversions). It's more advanced (some might even consider it a bit hackish)

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np


Base = ct.c_ushort

NpPtr = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(
    dtype=Base,
    flags='C_CONTIGUOUS',
    #ndim=1,
)

CtPtr = ct.POINTER(Base)


@ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.c_int, ct.c_int, NpPtr)
def callback_np(w, h, data):
    print("\ncallback_np:")
    #print(data, type(data), type(data).__mro__, hex(data.value))
    #print(data._ndim_, data._dtype_, data._shape_, data._type_, data._objects)
    img = np.ctypeslib.as_array(ct.POINTER(Base).from_address(ct.addressof(data)), shape=(h, w))
    #img = np.ctypeslib.as_array(data, shape=(h, w))  # Original form
    print(img)


@ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.c_int, ct.c_int, CtPtr)
def callback_ct(w, h, data):
    print("\ncallback_ct:")
    img = np.ctypeslib.as_array(data, shape=(h, w))
    print(img)


def main(*argv):
    w = 2
    h = 3
    arr = np.array(range(h * w), dtype=Base)
    print("Array argument: ", arr, type(arr), arr.shape, arr.dtype, arr.ndim)
    callback_ct(w, h, np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(arr))
    callback_np(w, h, arr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q067323177]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Array argument:  [0 1 2 3 4 5] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (6,) uint16 1
>
> callback_ct:
> [[0 1]
>  [2 3]
>  [4 5]]
>
> callback_np:
> [[0 1]
>  [2 3]
>  [4 5]]
>
> Done.
> ```