# How to run a Fortran script with ctypes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fortran, ctypes

First of all I have no experience coding with fortran. I am trying to run a fortran code with python ctypes. I used the command `gfortran -shared  -g -o test.so test.f90` to convert my *test.f90* file (code below) to *test.so*.

After reading [C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011) and table in chapter "Fundamental data types" https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes I had a clue about passing the right data type in my python code like `ctypes.c_double(123)` for `real(kind=c_double)`. I received a `Type Error: wrong type`.
I have no idea about passing the right data type to `real(kind=c_double),dimension(*)` it seems like an array for me. On [Numpy array to ctypes with FORTRAN ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73483728/numpy-array-to-ctypes-with-fortran-ordering) and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html it is well explained that numpy is providing a ctype conversion. So I tried some random arrays to pass values with `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))`. Now I receiving another type error: `TypeError: item 2 in _argtypes_ has no from_param method`.

I shared my python code also below. I could not figure out which data types I need to pass in my function. I would be grateful for an explanation.

```
function sticksum( anzd, w, b, a, weight, val, maxTchan, sthresh) result(spek) bind(c, name="sticksum")
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

    real(kind=c_double) :: anzd
    real(kind=c_double) :: b,a
    real(kind=c_double),dimension(*) :: w,weight
    real(kind=c_double),dimension(*) :: val
    integer(kind=c_int) :: maxTchan
    real(kind=c_double) :: sthresh
    real(kind=c_double) :: spek

    integer :: i, t, j,anz
    real    :: stick, maxw
    
    
    anz = anzd
    spek = 123
    i=1
    t = w(i) * b + a + 1.5
    if(t >= 1) THEN
        spek = anz
        stick = 0. + val(t)
        maxw = weight(i)*stick
        do i=2,anz
            t = w(i) * b + a + 1.5
            if(t > maxTchan) exit
            stick = val(t)
            maxw = max(weight(i)*stick,maxw)
            if( (w(i)*w(i)-w(i-1)*w(i-1)) > 0.5) THEN
                spek = spek + maxw
                maxw = 0
            end if
        end do
    end if
end function sticksum
```

---

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np 
so_file = "./test.so"
my_functions = CDLL(so_file)

print(type(my_functions))

my_functions.sticksum_4.argtypes = [c_double,np.ndarray.ctypes,c_double,c_double,np.ndarray.ctypes,np.ndarray.ctypes,c_int, c_double]
my_functions.restype = c_double

anzd = c_double(123) 
w = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
b=c_double(123) 
a=c_double(123) 
weight=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
val=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
maxTchan=c_int(123)
sthresh=c_double(123)


sum = my_functions.sticksum_4(anzd,w,b,a,weight,val,maxTchan,sthresh)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to start by stating that *Fortran* is not among my skills - I came in touch with it ~5 times (other questions from *SO*).

I found a bunch of problems:

- *Fortran*:

  - **Arguments are passed by reference** to functions / subroutines ([[GNU.GCC]: Argument passing conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Argument-passing-conventions.html)). That took me an hour to figure out. After I fixed all the rest, I was getting *Access Violation* when even printing one such argument. I added the dummy function during investigation. Anyway, the simplest version is to specify *value* for the ones to be passed by value (the other way around would be to pass pointers from the calling code)
  - Since I am on *Win*, I had to add the *dllexport* attribute to each function to be exported by the *.dll* (I was also able to do it by passing */EXPORT* to the linker for each function). I had another setback, as when checking the function export, the tool that I primarily use (check [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)) doesn't show it:

    - *Dependencies*:

      [image: Img0]
    - *Dependency Walker*:

      [image: Img1]
  - 1<sup>st</sup> argument is the dimension, no need to be double
  - Other (minor) issues (like reorganizing, adding module stuff, ...)
- *Python*:

  - Argument types didn't match the ones from *Fortran* definition which yields (as stated by the *URL* in the question) *Undefined Behavior*. I illustrated 2 ways of passing *NumPy* arrays (the uncommented one seems a bit nicer to me).
    Note that when working with multidimensional arrays, axes order is different in *Fortran* and *C* (for example for *2D*, the former is **column major**)

Managed to get the example working (I have no idea what all the operations from *sticksum* are supposed to do).

- *dll00.f90*:

  ```
  module dll00

  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none

  contains

  #if 0
  function dummy(i0, d0) result(res) bind(C, name="dummy")
      !dec$ attributes dllexport :: dummy
      integer(kind=c_int), intent(in), value :: i0
      real(kind=c_double), intent(in), value :: d0
      integer(kind=c_int) :: res

      res = 1618
      print *, "xxx", res
      print *, "yyy", i0
      print *, "zzz", d0
  end function dummy
  #endif

  function sticksum(anz, w, b, a, weight, value, maxTchan, sthresh) result(spek) bind(C, name="sticksum")
      !dec$ attributes dllexport :: sticksum
      integer(kind=c_int), intent(in), value :: anz, maxTchan
      real(kind=c_double), intent(in), value :: b, a, sthresh
      real(kind=c_double), intent(in), dimension(*) :: w, weight, value
      real(kind=c_double) :: spek

      integer :: i, t, j
      real :: stick, maxw

      spek = 123
      i = 1
      t = w(i) * b + a + 1.5
      if (t >= 1) then
          spek = anz
          stick = 0. + value(t)
          maxw = weight(i) * stick
          do i = 2, anz
              t = w(i) * b + a + 1.5
              if (t > maxTchan) exit
              stick = value(t)
              maxw = max(weight(i) * stick, maxw)
              if ((w(i) * w(i) - w(i - 1) * w(i - 1)) > 0.5) then
                  spek = spek + maxw
                  maxw = 0
              end if
          end do
      end if
  end function sticksum

  end module dll00
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ctypes as cts
  import sys

  import numpy as np


  DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")

  ELEMENT_TYPE = cts.c_double

  DblPtr = cts.POINTER(cts.c_double)


  def np_mat_type(dim, element_type=ELEMENT_TYPE):
      return np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=element_type, shape=(dim,), flags="F_CONTIGUOUS")


  def main(*argv):
      dim = 5
      dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
      sticksum = dll.sticksum
      sticksum.argtypes = (cts.c_int, np_mat_type(dim), cts.c_double, cts.c_double, np_mat_type(dim), np_mat_type(dim), cts.c_int, cts.c_double)
      #sticksum.argtypes = (cts.c_int, DblPtr, cts.c_double, cts.c_double, DblPtr, DblPtr, cts.c_int, cts.c_double)  # @TODO - cfati: alternative
      sticksum.restype = cts.c_double

      if 0:
          dummy = dll.dummy
          dummy.argtypes = (cts.c_int, cts.c_double)
          dummy.restype = cts.c_int
          print(dummy(cts.c_int(3141593), cts.c_double(2.718282)))

      w = np.arange(dim, dtype=ELEMENT_TYPE)
      a = 1
      b = 2
      weight = np.arange(1, dim + 1, dtype=ELEMENT_TYPE)
      val = np.arange(2, dim + 2, dtype=ELEMENT_TYPE)
      #print(w, weight, val)

      mtc = 3
      stresh = 6

      res = sticksum(dim, w, b, a, weight, val, mtc, stresh)
      #res = sticksum(dim, np.asfortranarray(w, dtype=ELEMENT_TYPE).ctypes.data_as(DblPtr), b, a, np.asfortranarray(weight, dtype=ELEMENT_TYPE).ctypes.data_as(DblPtr), np.asfortranarray(val, dtype=ELEMENT_TYPE).ctypes.data_as(DblPtr), mtc, stresh)  # @TODO - cfati: alternative
      print("\n{:s} returned: {:.3f}".format(sticksum.__name__, res))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q075937942]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.f90
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "f:\Install\pc032\Intel\OneAPI\Version\compiler\2021.3.0\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe" /nologo /fpp /c dll00.f90
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll /LIBPATH:"f:\Install\pc032\Intel\OneAPI\Version\compiler\2021.3.0\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win" dll00.obj
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.f90
> dll00.lib
> dll00.mod
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
> sticksum returned: 5.000
>
> Done.
> ```

Might also be interesting to read:

- [[SO]: What is numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes exacty doing (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68505437/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to convert a ctypes C pointer to a Numpy array? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67327122/4788546)
- [[SO]: How can i cast a double pointer ctype to numpy array? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58784385/4788546)